# centos docker image not working on gitlab docker runner

Tags: linux, docker, centos, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

Im trying to use centos as an base image for my gitlab runner. Here is my ci file:

```
build:
  stage: build
  image: centos
  script:
    - echo hello
```

And the result i get is:

```
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): Error response from daemon: Failed to mount; dmesg: <4>[16416949.641238] XFS (dm-17): xlog_recover_process_ophdr: bad clientid 0x0
<4>[16416949.641247] XFS (dm-17): log mount/recovery failed: error -5
<4>[16416949.641332] XFS (dm-17): log mount failed
: mount /dev/mapper/docker-249:0-392963-81a5b677997be1f6a6063db7650f5216985cbe7e5bc733ad2d7c245c057c0ceb-init:/var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/81a5b677997be1f6a6063db7650f5216985cbe7e5bc733ad2d7c245c057c0ceb-init, data: nouuid: input/output error (executor_docker.go:740:0s)
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: What is the host operating system on which the gitlab runner will be run?

Comment: Oracle linux 7.6

Answer (score 1):

If this is about a gitlab runner executed on a local GitLab instance, you would need to know, on that GitLab server instance, the output of `docker version` and `docker info`.

For instance, [this issue](https://community.e.foundation/t/solved-help-building-e-for-oneplus-5t/7956/2) was resolved when using to [overlay FS](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/).

For instance, regarding an [Oracle Linux](https://www.oracle.com/linux/technologies/) host, consider [`oracle/docker-images` issue 1211](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/issues/1211), especially [this comment](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/issues/1211#issuecomment-481525340) which includes the same `nouuid: input/output error` message.
It was followed by:

> Please switch to using either the overlay2 storage driver on an XFS file system or btrfs.
>   You're using the default devicemapper storage engine and that's breaking because of limitations of that engine.